# Count non-blank values after a cartesian product in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hope my description is accurate; improvements welcome.
I have 2 tables in Excel.
In Table1 there are 2 columns, A and B. It can be a many to many relationship.
In Table2 there are 2 columns, A and B. These are distinct entries.
Table1-ColumnB and Table2-ColumnA are the same values - a foreign key if you will.

I have a list of disctinct values from Table1-ColumnA in Result-List. I need to know if for each item in this list, if after a join on the foreign key, if all the associated values in Table2-Column2 are blank. (I don't need to know what content it has, only if it has content.)

This all needs to be done in a single cell in excel.

[image: Tables and result]

Comment: Can you add a basic example of data and desired outcome? Do any of your columns have a unique constraint?

Comment: @freekvd I tried a screenshot, not enough points... will try edit and add tables.

Comment: I had hoped I could adapt the formula found here [Sum of vlookup using array formula](http://superuser.com/questions/557447/sum-of-vlookup-using-array-formula). The first answer relies on the correct ordering of the data, which I can't; and I could get the second one to work - I think it has to do with the ISNUMBER portion, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone knows how to get the result you want using array formulas, please tell us. I do not think it is possible... Therefore I use VBA. This is my coded solution (UDF):

```
Option Explicit
Function Results(cell As Range, table_1 As Range, table_2 As Range) As String
Dim aTable1() As Variant
Dim aTable2() As Variant
aTable1 = table_1.Value
aTable2 = table_2.Value
Dim i As Long, j As Long 'counters

For i = 1 To UBound(aTable1, 1)
    If aTable1(i, 1) = cell.Value Then
        For j = 1 To UBound(aTable2, 1)
            If aTable1(i, 2) = aTable2(j, 1) Then
                If Not IsEmpty(aTable2(j, 2)) Then
                    Results = Results & aTable2(j, 1) & " has content, "
                Else
                    Results = Results & aTable2(j, 1) & " has no content, "
                End If
            End If
        Next
        If Results = vbNullString Then
            Results = aTable1(i, 2) & " NOT FOUND"
            GoTo Ending
        End If
    End If
Next
Results = Left(Results, Len(Results) - 2)
If (Len(Results) - Len(Replace(Results, "has", ""))) / 3 = _
(Len(Results) - Len(Replace(Results, "no", ""))) / 2 Then
    Results = "BLANK - " & Results
End If

Ending:
End Function
```

This is the result you get:
[image: UDF]

You can also use usual Range references, i.e. in `I3` I could have also inserted this formula: `=Results(H3,B$3:C$13,E$3:F$10)`.

Paste the code into VBA Editor (**Alt** + **F11**), in the newly inserted "Module1" (not in "ThisWorkbook" or "Sheet" modules)

Comment: thanks for the info. Once pasted in VBA editor, how do I get it to run on my data? Also, I get circular reference issues with the code `Results(H3,B$3:C$13,E$3:F$10)` that you pasted. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks @ZygD; I have figured out what you did in the results table. Makes sense now ... my spreadsheet was set up differently, so I had errors! Thanks.

Comment: The reason I haven't accepted yours as the answer is that I can't have a macro in the workbook. So I am hoping that someone else comes up with the array answer. Yours is a great solution though, thank you.